# what is Difference between $httpParamSerializerJQLike and json.stringify

Tags: angularjs, json

Here i wrote simple code  for saving data into api when i user `data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(savingdata)` is Binding data into server side but when i use    `data: JSON.stringify(savingdata)` its not Binding at server side what is the reason

```
 this.saveEmp = function (savingdata) {
        var sersave = $http({
            url: Privateurl2 + 'SaveEmpData',
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ;charset=utf-8'
            },

          //  data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(savingdata),
            data: JSON.stringify(savingdata),


        })
        return sersave;
    }
```

Comment: Your server does not accept JSON as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It may accept JSON as `application/json` but that's impossible to tell from here

Comment: FYI: `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` produces a string in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. `JSON.stringify` produces a string in `application/json` format

Comment: @phill could u plz arange my above data into Json.stringify(somedata),Beacause wen i use as stringify it not Binding

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If your server is expecting `urlencoded` form data and it works when you send it `urlencoded` form data, why are you trying to send it JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask

> what is Difference between $httpParamSerializerJQLike and json.stringify

The answer is simple. The former produces a string in *form-url-encoded* format, the latter *JSON*. To illustrate...

```
const savingdata = {
  foo: 'abc',
  bar: 123,
  baz: ['A', 'B']
}

$httpParamSerializerJQLike(savingdata)
// <- foo=abc&bar=123&baz%5B%5D=A&baz%5B%5D=B

JSON.stringify(savingdata)
// <- {"foo":"abc","bar":123,"baz":["A","B"]}
```

---

As for why one works with your server and the other does not; you are setting the request `Content-type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you attempt to send a JSON formatted request body, your server will fail to decode it because it does not match the format you specified.

Your server *may* be able to handle a JSON request payload (if it has been coded / configured to do so) in which case you can simply use the AngularJS defaults and use

```
return $http.post(Privateurl2 + 'SaveEmpData', savingdata)
```

This will set the `Content-type` to `application/json` and will use `JSON.stringify` to serialize the request payload.

If your server is not set up to handle requests in this format, the operation will obviously fail.

Comment: even i use headers:{cotent-type':'application/json'} data:json.string(somedata) its fail

Comment: *"If your server is **not set up to handle requests in this format**, the operation will obviously fail."*